# A Hard integral in 2-D.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

I'm having a trouble integrating  (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) the following formula:

$$\frac{t}{|B(x,t)|}\int_{B(x,t)}  \frac{||y||}{(t-||x-y||^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} dy $$

where $B(x,t)$ is the ball with center $x$ and radius t,

$|B(x,t)|$ is the area of the ball

After a change of variables:

$$\frac{t}{|B(x,t)|}\int_{B(x,t)}  \frac{||y||}{(t-||x-y||^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} dy =\frac{1}{|B(0,t)|}\int_{B(0,1)}  \frac{||x+tz||}{(1-||z||^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} dz$$

In polar coordinates:
$$ \frac{1}{|B(0,t)|}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}  \frac{||x+t\ r \ e^{i\theta}||}{(1-r^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} dr d\theta$$

But even in polar coordinates I cannot solve it.

Any advice will be helpfull. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm confused by your notation. As far as I can tell, $x$ is a vector but $tre^{i\theta}$ is a scalar. So you how are you adding them together?

Comment: Using the euler notation
$$tre^{i\theta} =t*r (cos(\theta),sin(\theta)) $$